# Python - falha de update() em unir dicionários

Tags: python, sql-update, dicionário

Olá
Pesquisei e encontrei que dicionárioA.update(dicionárioB) é capaz de unir os dois dicionários. Testei e de fato funciona. Mas no programinha exercício abaixo, ele não une, mas guarda apenas o último dicionário que guardo. A parte do programa que mostro isso parece complexo, mas é bem simples, do meu nível. É um cadastro de um jogador de futebol e gols que fez em algumas partidas. Em tese eu teria um dicionário com vários dicionário_jogador inseridos nele, mas só consigo fazer isso em uma lista (no exemplo nomeada cadastrados), mas não no dicionário (no exemplo nomeado in_dict. Eis o código:

```
# declaração de variáveis
gols = 0
marcou = 0
ficha = dict()
jogos = list()
gols = list()
jogo = ''
cadastrados = list()
in_dict = dict()
# cadastro de jogador
while True:
    part = 1
    #ficha.clear()
    ficha['nome'] = input('Nome: $: ')
    ficha['ano'] = int(input('Ano: $: '))
    ficha['time'] = input('Time: $: ')
    ficha['torneio'] = input('Torneio: $: ')
    ficha['jogadas'] = int(input('Partidas realizadas: $: '))
    print('Gols marcados por partida: ')
    while True: 
        jogos.append('jogo_'+str(part))
        gols.append(int(input('Gols: $ ')))
        part += 1
        sn = input('Novo jogo? [S/N] $ ').upper()
        if sn in 'Nn':
            break
# criação do dicionário
    ficha.update(zip(jogos, gols))
    # dicionário1.update(dicionário2) une os 2 dicionários
    # zip transforma duas listas em tuplas {key: valor} gerando um dicionário
    print('ficha_1', ficha) <--- PRINT DE CONTROLE
    jogos.clear()
    gols.clear()
    cadastrados.append(ficha.copy()) <--- AQUI A FICHA É ACRESCIDA A UMA LISTA E ok EM JUNTAR VÁRIOS DICIONÁRIOS NA LISTA
    in_dict.update(ficha) <--- AQUI APENAS O ÚLTIMO CADASTRO(FICHA) DO JOGADOR FICA NO DICIONÁRIO in_dict
    print('cadas', cadastrados, 'in_dict', in_dict) <--- PRINT DE CONTROLE
    sn = input('Novo cadastro? $ ').upper()
    if sn in 'Nn':
        break
print('ficha_2',ficha) <--- PRINT DE CONTROLE

resposta do terminal para um teste (para identificar onde são gerados ver PRINTS DE CONTROLE):
ficha_1 {'nome': 'b', 'ano': 2, 'time': 's', 'torneio': 's', 'jogadas': 2, 'jogo_1': 2, 'jogo_2': 3} (último cadastro criado)
cadas [{'nome': 'a', 'ano': 1, 'time': 's', 'torneio': 'r', 'jogadas': 2, 'jogo_1': 0, 'jogo_2': 1}, {'nome': 'b', 'ano': 2, 'time': 's', 'torneio': 's', 'jogadas': 2, 'jogo_1': 2, 'jogo_2': 3}] lista com os dois cadastros do teste
in_dict {'nome': 'b', 'ano': 2, 'time': 's', 'torneio': 's', 'jogadas': 2, 'jogo_1': 2, 'jogo_2': 3} dicionário apenas com o último cadastro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá, primeiro você tem de entender como um dicionário funciona.

O dicionário tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
Dicionário[Chave] = valor
```

ou também pode ser mostrado da seguinte forma:

```
Dicionário = {Chave: valor}
```

Chaves em um Dicionário são **únicas**, não há como duplicar uma chave num dicionário.

De forma resumida, se eu fizer um dicionário com uma chave X e valor Y, e logo então utilizar a mesma chave com um valor Z, ele irá sobrescrever o valor Y que estava dentro da chave, pois não é possível criar uma chave que já tem no dicionário; apenas modifica-la ou sobrescreve-la.

Pelo que vi no seu script mais recomendado é criar dicionários dentro de dicionário, utilizando o nome da pessoa como indentificação:

Exemplo:

```
Dicionario['Antonio'] = {}  
Dicionario['Antonio']['jogo'] = valor
...
```

vai indo...

Dicionário serve exatamente para facilitar a busca, e se você está fazendo um dicionário de usuários, qual a melhor forma de procura-los no dicionário? usando CPF, nome do usuário, id do usuário no banco de dados...

Um exemplo que uso bastante no trabalho é usar dicionários para dividir usuários por estado.  Exemplo:

```
# pegar todos e-mails de clientes de São Paulo
for i in dicionario['SP']
     i['e-mail']
```

Mas é isso, boa sorte.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deixe-me enganar pelo teste que fiz com update. Criei 3 dicionários com o mesmo nome (a), mas com valores internos diferentes, não me dei conta disso; assim fiz 3 vezes a.update(a) e OK, ai fiz inicialmente ficha.update(ficha) e depois o do exemplo in_dict.update(ficha), dando sempre substituição. Fiz como sugeriu e funcionou OK.